# Comparing modification of $resource result after edition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using $resource to make my Rest Requests.

I want to to put a result into a scope array to modify it.

I would like to know if a value has been change and remove those change if a cancel button is pressed.

here is a plunker illustrating what I want to do.

http://plnkr.co/edit/L0AROr58DMRNfU8AX6kX?p=preview

My problem is that when I modify "$scope.centres", "$scope.centresBackup" is also modify !

I don't understand why, I would like to know how to understand the mecanic behind and how to do what I want.

*** JS ***

```
    var RestRequest = $resource('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', null,
  {'test' :{
      'method' : 'GET',
      'params' : {'address':'test'}
    }
  });
RestRequest.test().$promise.then(function(response) {
  $scope.centres = response.results[0].address_components;
  $scope.centresBackup = response.results[0].address_components;
});
  $scope.$watch('centresBackup', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log(newValue);
  }, true);

  $scope.editCentre = function(i) {
      $scope.centres[i].modif = true;
  }

  $scope.cancelEdit = function(i) {
      console.log(i);
      console.log('modified = ' + $scope.centres[i].short_name);
      console.log('backup = ' + $scope.centresBackup[i].short_name);
      $scope.centres[i].modif = false;
      //$scope.centres[i] = $scope.centresBackup[i];
  }
```

Comment: The simplest way would be to have a list of the modified ones, when the user is finished, join the two together or simply delete the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because both arrays  $scope.centres and $scope.centresBackup hase the same reference to the promise response.results[0].address_components instead of using just = , you can try with angular.copy, like this:

```
  $scope.centres = angular.copy(response.results[0].address_components);
  $scope.centresBackup = angular.copy(response.results[0].address_components);
```

I have tried this in your plunker and it seems fine.

Comment: Wonderful, a new angular feature discovered